# NET Core 7 Web API and MVC:- List<IFormFile> from MVC not received in WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Does anyone have idea why List is not recived in WebApi. If I just run a swagger, both model and IFormFile working perfectly and saved in database. If i run two projects Api and Mvc , mvc Iformfile is not received in api, screens below

MVC project - MVC Controller:
model and fileDetails are correctly uploaded,

[image]

API project - WebApiController:
model recevived from MVC, List are empty, Model saved correctly in database
[image]

i would like pass both models from MVC to API correctly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello have you tried the solution provided? Is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Answer (score 0):

> NET Core 7 Web API and MVC:- List from MVC not received in
> WebApi

It would be great if you could share you complete code snippet in order to investigate your issue. As you haven't shared the MVC code shippet how you are sending the request, thus, its hard to guide you on this.

However, I have tried to simulate your scenario in following way and successfully uploaded the list of [IFormFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Model:

```
public class MultipleFilesUploadModel
    {
        public List<IFormFile>? Files { get; set; }
        public string? Message { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

Load View:

```
 public IActionResult MultipleFileUpload()
        {
            MultipleFilesUploadModel model = new MultipleFilesUploadModel();
            return View(model);
        }
```

Upload List IFormFile:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult MultipleFileUpload(MultipleFilesUploadModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               
                if (model.Files!.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var file in model.Files)
                    {

                        string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/Files");

                        //Would create folder if that does not exist
                        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

                        //Getting File path and file name
                        string fileNameWithCompletePath = Path.Combine(path, file.FileName);

                        //Saving file into directory
                        using (var stream = new FileStream(fileNameWithCompletePath, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            file.CopyTo(stream);
                        }

                    }
                    model.Message = "File has been uploaded successfully!";
                }
               
            }

            return View("MultipleFileUpload", model);
        }
```

View:

```
@model UploadFilesApp.Models.MultipleFilesUploadModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Multiple File Upload Sample in  .Net 7";

}

<form asp-action="MultipleFileUpload" asp-controller="UploadFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="col-12">
            <label class="col-form-label">Choose Multiple Files</label>
            <input asp-for="Files" class="form-control" multiple/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Files" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if (@Model.Message !=null)
    {
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        @Model.Message
    </div>
    }
    <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="col-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload Files</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Ouput:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** You can [refer to this example](https://github.com/kironiitdu/UploadFilesApp/tree/master). If you still would like to know more details on [Upload files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0).